# FLVPlayback custom ui: SeekBar component never creates SeekBarHandle

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flvplayback, seekbar

I've setup an FLVPlayback 2.5 component with no skin. Then I've added all the UI components and assigned them to the FLVPlayback instance. I'm using a PlayPauseButton, a SeekBar, a MuteButton, a VolumeBar and a FullScreenButton. All of the components had their graphics customized. Extra care was taken not to rename or delete any movieclips.

If I try the custom components by publishing the movie, everything works fine.

The problem arises when I dynamically load this SWF into another one. The parent SWF loads the playback controls and instantiates everything and starts the video playerback.

What doesn't work is the SeekBar's and VolumeBar's Handle. It just doesn't appear. If I put a trace() in those MovieClips, they never appear on the console, as if they are never created.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I've found a work-around:

Assign the custom controls to the FLVPlayback instance when VideoEvent.PLAYING_STATE_ENTERED is fired. You'll see some sort of a glitch when the components start working cause when you assign them to the FLVPlayback they position themselves and maybe hide something (for example in the PlayPauseButton), so until that you can hide all of them or something like that.

If anybody has any more info please post!